# How can I get a copy of the SQL generated by Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

If I save a table in Management Studio's Table Designer for example, I believe it runs DDL SQL in the background. Is it possible for me to grab this SQL so that I can save it to a file?

Comment: In SQL Server 2012, once you've changed a table in the designer, you can go to Table Designer > Generate Change Script. Not sure if that option is there on previous versions.

Comment: Ah, excellent and its in 2008. Please write this up as an answer.

Comment: The long term answer is to become well-versed with T-SQL so you don't rely on  GUI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modern versions of SSMS (2008+ at least) allow you to generate a change script once you have made changes to a table using the graphical designer. You go to the menu item Table Designer > Generate Change Script.

[image]

That said, I agree with Thomas. In the long term, you should be proficient at T-SQL so that you can write `ALTER TABLE` scripts without the help of the wizard / graphical designers. They often do things you don't want to do.

Comment: Yes.. hopefully seeing the scripts will help reduce my dependence on the designer.

Answer (score 0):

You can just go to the table after it is created in SSMS and right click and then select the Script options in the menu.

Comment: I don't think you can get ALTER statements like that, say, if I add a new column.